# Magento2 not showing success page cache_invalidate

Tags: checkout, cache, magento-2.0, payment-methods

I am developing website in magento 2 
My current version is magento 2.0.2 currently I am unable to see order success page. Magento keep showing ajax loader, and website goes down for certain interval of time. debug.log show following error.

> [2017-03-22 06:48:42] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://magento-dir/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/44a12dc3f7801837cb3b853378e23bb3/payment-information","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_category_26","catalog_category"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []

also attaching screenshot.
[image: Checkout page]

[image: Order Placed]

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing and cleaning cache

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

and

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

also i would like to point out that Magento 2  authentication does not work on the top-level domains like `localhost` Just use a second-level domain like `localhost.com` if you are using localhost.

Comment: Not working. I am already using local IP instead of localhost also disabled flush cache.